# Mobaxterm connects to Ubuntu server through SSH network error: software caused connection abort

Tags: ssh, disconnect

MobaXterm v21.1 connects to Ubuntu  20.04.3 LTS server through SSH
disconnects all the time after short idle time, with this error:
network error: software caused connection abort.
I tried everything written here: https://programmerah.com/mobaxterm-connects-to-ubuntu-server-through-ssh-network-error-software-caused-connection-abort-43897/

- changed setting of Mobaextrem to keep alive
- edited /etc/ssh/sshd_config

  - TCPKeepAlive yes
  - ClientAliveInterval 60

I even left a top command running in the terminal, didn't help.

Is there an option that the disconnect is coming from the Ubuntu side ?
Any idea how to solve it will be much appreciated.

** edit **

checking `/var/log/auth.log`

I see:

```
Mar  3 01:12:09 COSDEVVIS12 sshd[1529012]: Timeout, client not responding from user naomi <myip> port 59737
```

Beginning of /etc/ssh/sshd_config is:

```
#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.103 2018/04/09 20:41:22 tj Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.
/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
```

I run

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -ddd -p 10022
```

I get:

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config: line 5: Bad configuration option: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
```

...

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
```

Answer (score 0):

How long does it take to disconnect when you are idle?

Try changing your ClientAliveInterval to something smaller, like 5 (this will send the null packet every 5 seconds, instead of every minute as you have set now).

Comment: I don't know exactly, but less then 2 hours. I'm working with jupyter notebook, running on chrome on my local computer. I train dl networks, and it gets disconnected in the middle of training. I will try to change ClientAliveInterval as you suggested.

Comment: changing ClientAliveInterval to 5, don't solve the problem.

Comment: It could be that the problem lies in the connection reliability on your side. Try this -- connect to your Ubuntu Server in MobaXterm, then open a command prompt in Windows and ping the server for awhile `ping server.ip.here -t` and see if you get any time-outs.

Comment: The beginning of your /etc/ssh/sshd_config file is missing "Include" ---

`Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf`